# Where does couchdb store admin user data on MacOSX?

Tags: macos, couchdb, couchdbx

I'm looking to remove all traces of couchdbx from a mac, and install couchdb from source. For some reason, though, the newly installed couchdb seems to still be using (older) admin user/login data.

Where is this data stored/how do I remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to check that `~/Library/Application Support/CouchbaseServer` is empty as well.